# dont know which selector to use for tab/accordion div to close/dehighlight the active ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-selectors

the title is a bit confusing but heres my problem:

i want a little info box in my shop with more detailed informations about the actual product
so i build this little tab thing but my problem is if the user clicks another tab the old one should dehighlight (and loose his little tooltip bottom thingy) but i dont know how i can select them correctly

**JQUERY:**

```
  $('.info-tab').click(function(){
  var seeit = $(this).find('img').css('display');
  var otheron = $(this).siblings().css('background');


  if( seeit === 'none' && otheron !== '#de3f3f'){
        $(this).css({
        background:'#de3f3f',
        color: '#f6f6f6'
        });
        $(this).find('img').fadeIn(200);

  }else{
        $(this).css({
          background:'#eee',
          color: '#565656'
        });
        $(this).find('img').fadeOut(1);
  }


});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="info-tab-box-wrapper">
 <div class="info-tab">More Details<img src="images/tooltip_spitze.png"></div>
 <div class="info-tab">Produktion<img src="images/tooltip_spitze.png"></div>
 <div class="info-tab">Lieferzeiten<img src="images/tooltip_spitze.png"></div>
 <p class="txt-notes">*INFORMATIONS HERE</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#info-tab-box-wrapper{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin: 25px 0 0 0;
}

.info-tab {
width: 25.5%;
height: 26px;
background: #eee;
float: left;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin: 0 5px 30px 0;
-webkit-border-radius:2px;
-moz-border-radius:2px;
border-radius:2px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
font-family: 'Titillium Web', Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 100%;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
color: #565656;
}

.info-tab:hover {
background: #de3f3f;
color: #f6f6f6;
}

.info-tab img {
display: none;
margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

my fiddle is not working correctly but maybe helps visualising: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6KtNw/6/)

Comment: adding inline style is simple...undoing it isn't as clear cut since you have to keep track of what css is to start, also is more involved checking css properties....far easier to toggle classes that manage the css, removing a class is very simple. Suggest you create rules for `.info_tab.active` toggle `active` class

Comment: so u mean i just need to create classes which i toggle on/off but my problem is how do i dehighlight(toggleoff)the tab that i dont want when clicked on another with not writing endless code? and my tooltip thingy needs do his job too. sorry for my bad englisch :/

Comment: simple... before adding class to new one  `$('.info-tab.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active')`...those 2 line remove a bunch of your code...and are easier to read logic wise

Comment: ok i updated my fiddle but suddenly all hell breaks lose and classes are added wildly :D

http://jsfiddle.net/6KtNw/11/

Comment: think about what toggle does...if it's not there it adds it. Now you have 2 classes in play( not sure you need both) so need to be more explicit what you want done with them http://jsfiddle.net/6KtNw/12/

Comment: seems to me `inactive` is default state, so not sure why need to add/remove it

Comment: common practice for manipulating visual state in the DOM, glad it helped